# Using two types of animation together

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I'm trying to animate elements in my webpage by using css3 and gsap library. One of my elements which is my menu item has the following code in css3:

```
.loaded .main-menu .item:nth-child(1){
top:calc(50% - 25px);
left:calc(50% - 25px);
background-color:green;
opacity:0;
-webkit-animation:moveicon1 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
-moz-animation:moveicon1 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
-o-animation:moveicon1 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
animation:moveicon1 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
}

@keyframes moveicon1{
100%{-ms-transform:translate(0px,-160px) rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:translate(0px,-160px) rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:translate(0px,-160px) rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:translate(0px,-160px) rotate(360deg);
transform:translate(0px,-160px) rotate(360deg);
opacity:0.8;}
}
```

I've done above for all prefixes. And the other hand I wrote these code via gsap based on following code:

```
TweenLite.to('.loaded .main-menu .item:nth-child(1)', 1, {x:0,z:0,y:-160,rotation:360,opacity:0.8, ease:Back.easeOut});
```

An idea to use both together is using gsap when css3 is not define in client's browser:

```
    if (!Modernizr.cssanimations){
// GSAP Codes
}
```

I know that gsap and css3 has the same speed But the question is can I use both together and browser run each one that has more speed. So like when the computer is in Power Saver mode , run the gsap and when javascript is off run the css3.
I hope that wasn't non suitable question and you can help me.
If it's not possible, help me to recognize when I should use which one? Javascript or css3?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I really don't think it is a very good idea to combine CSS3 animations with any type of JavaScript-based animation framework (GSAP or not). Drop one of them. Having said that though, after using GSAP for quite a few years now, I can confidently recommend to you to _not_ use CSS3 in this particular case and do all your animations using GSAP. A couple of recommended links: **[Why GSAP](https://greensock.com/why-gsap/)** and **[CSS Animations vs JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)**

Comment: @TahirAhmed  Thanks for comment, Actually after reading the articles you've mentioned and many others I found out you're absolutely right. And it's better to choose GSAP instead of css3. But one question, what if javascript of a client's browser is off? is it good idea to use css3 animations in .no-js class?

Comment: you could but I think with JavaScript turned off, you may have bigger things to worry about than doing animations. I suggest to have a read on the topic of _Progressive Enhancement_ for more details.

Comment: @TahirAhmed It should be noted that both links are written by Green Sock people

Comment: @vals Yes, I noticed that. I think when the number of animations and elements which there is an animation on them, is high, javascript has leg more than css3. But in the articles above they told css3 has leg more than js. I don't know. I think because of compatibility it's better to use GSAP. but about speed Im not sure, yet.

Comment: I don't know what is better...  I am just saying that you **need** to know, when reading something about how great is XYZ, if the one that wrote it is independent, or from XYZ company ...